# Charset and POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, http-headers

I have a Rails 2.3.5 application that is working fine with UTF-8 and international characters. Now I have made some integration to a payment gateway where I POST some data, wait a while and get a POST back. The problem is that when I get that post back the international characters are broken. Instead of "sørensen" I get: "sÃ¸rensen". If I do an "iconv -t ISO-8859-1 -f UTF8" it gets correctly converted to the former (I do that from a OS X command prompt). I have examined the POST request with logger.info(request.headers.inspect) in my controller and I can see that no charset parameter is given.

The POST from the gateway should be ISO-8859-1 according to them - is the problem that Rails thinks that it is UTF8? Is that consistent with the issue I am seeing?

I know that one solution is to simply convert the params-hash with Iconv in the controller but I would like to know what is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Jacob

Comment: I have the exact problem. Rails 3.2. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did - I posted an answer with the solution. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

In the model:

```
FIELDS_TO_FIX=[:name, :city, :address]  

# DIBS sucks and sends UTF8 in some strange encoding. So we have to do an array.pack on
# strings when posting to DIBS and unpack them at callback.
#
def self.fix_encoding(params)  
  FIELDS_TO_FIX.each do |f|
    next if params[f].nil?
    params[f]=params[f].unpack("M")[0].force_encoding("UTF-8")
  end
  params
end
```

In the create action of the controller:

```
  params[:booking]=Booking.fix_encoding(params[:booking])
```

And in the view that posts to the external resource:

```
<input type="hidden" name="booking[name]" value="<%= [@booking.name].pack("M") %>" />
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

can you verify that the request headers are set appropriately in the POST. you can see the acceptable values in the following link. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers